# Update stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures

Hey guys this is a stored procedure that updates the PrevLoc field..but I want my proc to insert the upadate in to  different field I do not want this to modify the original field as I still want to keep it as it is.Could you guys help on this?I greatly appreciate it.Thanks all

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[updateloc]

AS
UPDATE Stage.Loc
SET PrevLoc=RTRIM(PrevLoc)
UPDATE Stage.Loc
SET PrevLoc = REPLACE(PrevLoc, substring(PrevLoc, LEN(PrevLoc) -
        (CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(PrevLoc)))+ 1, LEN(PrevLoc)), dbo.parsLocat(PrevLoc))--    --this is a function that I use 


SET changedLoc=PrevLoc---this doesnt work

GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is `changeLoc` a column in the table?

You would just need to set that property instead.

These changes would leave `PrevLoc` with no changes at all, and process that value into `changeLoc`

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[updateloc]

AS
UPDATE Stage.Loc
SET changeLoc=RTRIM(PrevLoc)

UPDATE Stage.Loc
SET changeLoc = REPLACE(changeLoc, substring(changeLoc, LEN(changeLoc) -
        (CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(changeLoc)))+ 1, LEN(changeLoc)), dbo.parsLocat(changeLoc))--    --this is a function that I use 

GO
```

Comment: @JDwyer...that was so useful..it works great.I do appreciate it.But I have one more question for you.If you see the first update is for trimming aspace .Instead of doing two updates is there a way to use a variable for the first and assign that to the function.Thanks again all..

Comment: It is probably simpler to leave it as 2 updates. In order to combine this you would need to use cursors. Keep in mind that your updates are happening for every row in the table, so there is no filtering/table seeking so having 2 queries is not going to make much of a difference.

Comment: Thanks again..I do appreciate it..it does make sense